# Partition a graph into k connected subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory, np-complete

I have a planar graph $G = (V, E)$ and I want to randomly generate partitions of $G$ into $k$ connected components. In the simple version, the size of the connected components needs to be as close to equal as possible (i.e., no more than $1$ apart). In the harder version, every vertex has a weight, and the sums of the weights needs to be as close to equal as possible.

How can I go about doing this? I feel like this problem has a flavor of NP-hardness, but I don't care about things like minimal edge cuts. Literally any division works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The weighted version of the problem is NP-complete, even for $k=2$, because we can reduce subset sum to it. Suppose we have integers $x_1, \dots, x_n$, with $x_1 + \dots + x_n = S$, and want to find a subset with sum $T$. Give the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,2}$ (which is planar!) vertex weights as follows: the $n$ vertices on one side are assigned weights $x_1, \dots, x_n$, one vertex on the other side is assigned weight $S-2T$, and the other vertex weight $0$.

The total weight of all vertices is $2S-2T$. If a partition into two connected subgraphs, each with weight $S-T$ (as equal as possible) exists, then the component containing the vertex of weight $S-2T$ also contains a bunch of vertices whose total weight is $T$: the subset we were looking for.

Comment: Oh wow, this is great. Is there a similar reduction to the unweighted case?

Comment: Unclear. If we try to do the same thing directly, replacing a weighted vertex with some group of unweighted vertices, then we run into a problem: unary subset sum is in P. In other words, hard instances of subset sum require exponentially large weights. In the $k=3$ case, we may be able to get somewhere with [3-partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition), which is strongly NP-complete, but that's harder to embed in a planar graph.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this last part. For the unweighted case, where does the unary subset sum problem come in? Is the weight of vertex $i$ just $i$? I was thinking that you couldn't use the same encoding because trivially all vertices have weight 1, and subset-sum when all the weights are 1 (or constant) is trivial.

Comment: You can simulate having weights on vertices as follows: instead of having a vertex of weight $k$, add a complicated structure on $k-1$ more vertices hanging off of that vertex, so that your connected subgraph can only contain that structure by containing the vertex. But this is very much like a unary encoding of weights: the graph you get has size proportional to the sum of the weights, not the sum of their logs.

Comment: Are there other strongly NP-complete problems that involve partitioning? I couldn't come up with a good reduction from 3-partition to the unweighted partitioning problem. What I tried was basically having every set element $x_i$ represented as a star graph with $x_i - 1$ vertices hanging off the central vertex, and then connecting all the central vertices. That doesn't work (isn't planar). Is there a better approach?

Comment: By the way, I also got pretty far with the following approach: if a $k$-partition exists, there is a spanning tree of the graph that generates it. Checking if a tree can be partitioned can be done quickly. But, generating all possible spanning trees is hard -- the fastest algorithm I could find is $O(N+|V|+|E|)$. $N$ is the complexity of the graph, which can be huge.

Comment: And checking all the possible spanning trees can take a while - there can be exponentially many. (Though most of the partitions we get will be redundant.) I haven't come up with other approaches, and to be honest I just got my list of NP-complete problems to try from Wikipedia.